# labeling geojson points in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, labeling

I have a map that I can load geojson data into and display it without any problem. Now I would like to add labels to the data points. I know leaflet does not have a good way to do this. I messed with the tooltip option and that works, but when the points get to close together the tooltips overlap, and I really need to prevent that, as there could be quite a number of points in a small area. (see Pic) I need help finding and implementing an option.

```
var osm = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
  layers: [osm],
  center: [lat, long],
  zoom: zoom,
  zoomSnap: 0,
});

 var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 4,
        fillColor: "#FF0101",
        color: "#0163FF",
        weight: 10,
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 1
};

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
   var url = "Myotherwebpage";
   var description = ('<h3>' + feature.properties.Name +
                      '</h3><p><a href=' + url + '>Let's Go</a></p>');          
   var popupContent = description;
   layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
};   

mymap.zoomControl.setPosition('topright');

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("mydata/myfile.geojson", {

  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions,);
  }
});
geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

[image]

Ok, I have a working hack here. I'll share the code, and hope for improvements. I wrote my own functions that loop through the points and labels and show, or hide the tooltips based on whether or not they would overlap any existing point or tooltip. I'm using the `permanent: true,` option to show them in the first place. I have my map load zoomed out and then use `<body onload="getmap()">` to call a sub that resets the zoom. I have my labels hide on `mymap.on('zoomstart', function(e)` and then show on `mymap.on('zoomend', function(e)`. I'm clueless how bad or slow this is, but it works.

tt = tooltip, l = layer.

```
    var ct = 0;  //this is so if a lbl can't show move it and try again
                 // and use this to prevent a recursive loop.
    let labels = [];  //holds all my geometries for hit testing

    function getpointrect() {    //gets point circles
        geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (l) {
            var pt = mymap.latLngToLayerPoint({
                lat: l.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lon: l.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
                });
                var size = l.getRadius() + l.options.weight; 
            let rects = [{x:pt.x - size,y:pt.y - size, w: size * 2, h: size * 2}];
            labels.push(rects);
        });
    };



    function setlabel(tt, l){     //loops through labels and gets geometries
                               //and checks for hits
    var pt = mymap.latLngToLayerPoint({
                lat: l.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lon: l.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
                });
       var wd = getTextWidth(tt.getContent(), "regular 12px sans-serif");
       var y;
       if (tt.options.offset.y > 0) {   //fancy stuff for different lbl positions.
           y = -((tt.options.offset.y / 2) + 14);//manually set label height.
       }else{
           y = -tt.options.offset.y / 2;
       }; 
       let rects = [{x:pt.x - (wd / 2), y:pt.y + y, w: wd, h: 14}];          
       if (labels.length == 0) {//if array is empty adds first lable to the map
           labels.push(rects);
           mymap.openTooltip(tt);
       }else{
           if (testhit(rects) == false) { //checks the rest of the labels
               labels.push(rects);//adds visible labels to array
               mymap.openTooltip(tt);  //shows label
               ct = 0;
           }else{
              if (ct == 0) {//if label can't show, moves it, and tries again
                 tt.options.offset.y = -tt.options.offset.y;
                 ct++;
                 setlabel(tt, l);
              }else {
              ct = 0;
              };
           };
       };
    };

    function testhit(rect){//this gets the rectangles for the following math.
    var arrayLength = labels.length;
       var isoverlap = false;
       for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {//loops through labels and points
         var rct = (labels[i]);
         var ck = intersect(rect,labels[i]);
         if (ck == true){
           isoverlap = ck;
           return isoverlap;/overlaps
         };
       };
       return isoverlap;  does not overlap
    };
    function intersect(a, b) {   // all the fancy math that checks stuff
      return (a[0].x < b[0].x + b[0].w &&
      b[0].x < a[0].x + a[0].w &&          
      a[0].y < b[0].y + b[0].h &&          
      b[0].y < a[0].y + a[0].h)         
    };

    function getTextWidth(text, font) {//checks the label length.
       var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
       var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
       context.font = font;
       var metrics = context.measureText(text);
       return metrics.width;
    };
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you provided your solution as an answer, rather than as an "answer within a question".

Comment: I don't want to do that unless the code is good enough for others to use. I don't know anything about JavaScript, so there may be things that are done just terrible and  things that could be done much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [handy little library over on GitHub](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) which allows points to 'spiderfy'. This may help your situation depending on the size of your pop ups and the amount of information contained within those pop ups. [Here is a demo](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/demo.html) from the GitHub repo.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I should have made it more clear. My popups are fine, they have all the info I need and work properly. What I want is a static label near the points that just has the Name. I know I can't show all the labels at the same time so I would like it to show as many as possible at once. Then as the map was zoomed more labels would show.

Comment: Perhaps [clustering](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) would help solve your problem? This library helps with [static labels](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label). Maybe a combination of the libraries I've pointed to?

Comment: What I am looking for is something down [this](https://yakitoritabetai.github.io/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision/) line. I couldn't get that to work though, for some reason.

Comment: Now I understand. Yet another handy library to add to my list. I will look at it a little later tonight in detail and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I would love it if you could! I'm a farmer by trade and this project is my first ever with JavaScript and html so I'm kinda dumb figuring that stuff out.

Comment: I almost have a working situation now. I'm doing my own math and checking for overlap, then showing or hiding the tooltips based on that. I can do that during a zoomend event. I'd like to add all the tooltips as closed when the map loads, then call my function and open the ones I need. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Forgot I had a meeting last night. I'll look at it over the weekend.